# Adding a non standard Cordova plugin to Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I installed the plugin like this:

```
ionic plugin add manateeworks-barcodescanner
```

I see the plugin in the plugins directory, but I do not know how to use it inside a controller? With other cordova plugins one can include them in the controller like this:

```
.controller('MyController', function($cordovaCamera)
```

How should I include this barcode scanner plugin?

**I can use the plugin directly in the index.html template; but how should it be used inside a controller?**

Comment: Did you try to use the scanner object that is a global variable?

Comment: how do you know its a global object?

Comment: Their github says so https://github.com/manateeworks/phonegap-mwbarcodescanner

Comment: Did you try this on your phone or on your pc? Because a js should be added automatically to index.html with the scanner object

Comment: On the phone using ionic run android

Answer (score 0):

using `$window`

```
.controller('MyController', function($window)
```

The `manateeworks-barcodescanner` plugin export the name `scanner`

so, your can using `$window.scanner` to call the plugin method in controller